# ROCm Installation with Fedora 32

Tags: fedora, amd-gpu, amd-rocm

I have tried to install ROCm ( https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/ ) on Fedora 32 using the process that was described here https://rigtorp.se/notes/rocm/

The rocminfo function correctly identifies my Radeon RX 5700. Codes from hip-samples compile and link but running the code crashes the session or the entire system.

Has anyone else successfully installed ROCm with Fedora ?

The current kernel version for Fedora 32 is 5.8.10

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your usecase, I'd recommend using the official docker images for ROCm.
You can find them here:
https://hub.docker.com/u/rocm

There are images for various deep learning frameworks on ROCm as well as more generic ones like [rocm/terminal](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocm/rocm-terminal).

I have successfully used [rocm/tensorflow](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocm/tensorflow/) on my machine running Fedora 33 in the past. You also do not need the actual Docker engine, `podman` works just fine, too.